# wpf user control inside listview is becoming transparent

Tags: wpf

We are creating 8 usercontrols to show graphs of 8 patients inside a listview. The issue is that the usercontrols when zoomed-in are not totally opaque. Due to which the the items behind that usercontrol is also visible inside it. Please suggest what could be the cause.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: From what it sounds I'd put solid background on the controls, adding one more element if necessary. But really you should provide more info for adequate answer.